# Unhandled exception... Access Violation reading location

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, cuda, gpu

I'm following a tutorial on using NVIDIA/CUDA/etc. here: http://www.nvidia.com/content/gtc-2010/pdfs/2131_gtc2010.pdf

I'm trying to add two vectors in parallel, but I am having trouble with these memory access violations mentioned in the title of my post.

The error is occurring at my **printf line** **(I will post my code below)**, but if I comment it out I get taken to a file named *"dbgheap.c"* and I just get the same error message on line 1696 of that file (the file has 3268 lines)

The line is:

```
if (*pb++ != bCheck)
```

and the function that is in is:

```
extern "C" static int __cdecl CheckBytes(
    unsigned char * pb,
    unsigned char bCheck,
    size_t nSize
    )
{
    while (nSize--)
    {
        if (*pb++ != bCheck) //this is the line with the error
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

And the memory address location it says it can't access, I believe, are the locations of my "a", "b", and "c" variables (will post my code below).

So without further adieu, here is my code (sorry there are no comments):

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 10

__global__ void kernel() {
}

__global__ void add(int *a, int *b, int *c) {
    c[blockIdx.x] = a[blockIdx.x] + b[blockIdx.x];
}

void random_ints(int* a,int num) {
    for (int i = 0; i<num; i++)
        a[i] = rand();
}

int main () {
    int *a,*b,*c;
    int *dev_a, *dev_b, *dev_c;
    int size = N*sizeof(int);

    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a,size);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_b,size);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c,size);

    a = (int*)malloc(size);
    b = (int*)malloc(size);
    c = (int*)malloc(size);

    random_ints(a,N);
    random_ints(b,N);



    cudaMemcpy(dev_a,&a,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_b,&b,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    add<<<N,1>>>(dev_a,dev_b,dev_c);

    cudaMemcpy(&c,dev_c,size,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
        printf("%d + %d = %d\n",a[i],b[i],c[i]);

    free(a); free(b); free(c);
    cudaFree(dev_a);
    cudaFree(dev_b);
    cudaFree(dev_c);
    return 0;
}
```

If you need any clarifications just ask.

Thanks!

Comment: what does this `add<<<N,1>>>(dev_a,dev_b,dev_c);` mean? are you sure you know it? also, don't cast the return value of `malloc()` but instead check that it doesn't return `NULL`.

Comment: It tells add() to run N times in parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cudaMemcpy parameters are the actual pointers so no need to take their address before passing (unlike cudaMalloc).  Remove the &.

```
   cudaMemcpy(dev_a,a,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
   cudaMemcpy(dev_b,b,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
   add<<<N,1>>>(dev_a,dev_b,dev_c);

   cudaMemcpy(c,dev_c,size,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

I believe this is what is causing your memory corruption problems.

As a matter of form, I'd pass the length in and check it against blockIdx.x.

```
__global__ void add(int *a, int *b, int *c, int N) {
    if (blockIdx.x < N) { 
        c[blockIdx.x] = a[blockIdx.x] + b[blockIdx.x];
    }
}
```

I thought this was actually required but I'm guessing it isn't if the range fits in a single warp.  For N > 16, it will be necessary and the check will be a bit more complex (using threadIdx.x and blockDim.x).

Comment: Thank you!! That actually makes a lot of sense! (And I just went back to the tutorial slide and realized they took out the '&' when moving to the parallel addition example).

I won't have access to the machine until tomorrow, but I would be shocked if this didn't fix it. 


Thanks again! :)